# Help Extending currency controller

Tags: overrides, currency

I am trying to get all currency conversions to round up to the nearest dollar, which I have successfully done by hacking the core Currency.php file (/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php). I know this is not a good long term solution, but I can't seem to get a proper local extender going.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Magento 1.9.1

Here's what I have:

**app/code/local/CEM/Currencyround/controllers/RoundCurrency.php**

```
            <?php

            class CEM_Currencyround_RoundCurrency extends Mage_Directory_Model_Currency {
              public function format($price, $options = array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
                {
                /**
                 * CHANGE BELOW FOR CEMPEPTIDES ROUNDING DECIMALS UP "ceil()"
                 * */
                    return $this->formatPrecision(ceil($price), 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
                }
            }
```

**app/code/local/CEM/Currencyround/etc/config.xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <config>
              <modules>
                <CEM_Currencyround>
                  <version>1</version>
                </CEM_Currencyround>
              </modules>
             <frontend>
                    <routers>
                        <CEM_Currencyround>
                            <use>standard</use>
                            <args>
                                <module>CEM_Currencyround</module>
                                <frontName>CEM_Currencyround</frontName>
                            </args>
                        </CEM_Currencyround>
                    </routers>
                </frontend>
            </config>
```

**app/etc/modules/CEM_Currencyround.xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <config>
              <modules>
                <CEM_Currencyround>
                  <version>1</version>
                  <active>true</active>
                  <codePool>local</codePool>
                </CEM_Currencyround>
              </modules>
            </config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to override a model not a controller. 
You can override model using below code.
**app/code/local/CEM/Currencyround/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    ------
    <global>
        --------
        <models>
            <directory>
                <rewrite>
                    <currency>CEM_Currencyround_Model_RoundCurrency</currency>
                </rewrite>
            </directory>
        </models>
        --------
    </global>
    -------
</config>
```

**app/code/local/CEM/Currencyround/Model/RoundCurrency.php**

```
class CEM_Currencyround_Model_RoundCurrency extends Mage_Directory_Model_Currency {
// your overridden method
             }
```

Some useful links :

- http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/
- http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/
- http://alanstorm.com/magento_upgrade_rewrite_override

Comment: Thanks so much.  I clearly have to learn a lot about the magento structure.  Thanks also for the links!